# Unable to find the source which is setting logback properties

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using a framework which is using logback framework for logging. The logs are generated in format - {TimeStamp}_restTests.log and I am trying to figure out the source where the properties of the logback like file name, logging level are set.

There is a logback.xml in the framework but that is not the source as even if I rename it to logback_old.xml or comment out some code in it the logs are getting generated as it is.

I took reference from - https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html
and searched for logback-test.xml, logback.groovy etc as well but not luck.

I tried searching for keyword '_restTests' which is the postfix of log files in the framework but found nothing.

Please provide any pointers on this

Comment: are you developing a standard java app or jee? are you using a particular framework like spring or other?

Comment: Its a REST API Automation Framework using SPOCK-Groovy and Rest Template